# Mac OS: shell not recognising scp

Tags: bash, macos, unix, ssl, scp

I'm trying to execute the below command on my new MacBook and was getting the '-bash: sudo scp: command not found' error.
Please help me fixing this issue.

```
sudo scp -i Pem_File_Name.pem PHP_File_Name.php centos@Host_Path:/var/www/html/Folder_Name/
```

The Pen_File_Name, PHP_File_Name and Host_Path are replaced with their respected values.

Thanks in advance.

Geeth.

Comment: Try from terminal to run:    /usr/bin/scp .   if it's working, fix your PATH.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, I'd guess that you have something other than a normal space (maybe a non-breaking space) between "sudo" and "scp". The reason I think this is that the error message says the command "sudo scp" was not found -- but the command should be "sudo" (which should then run "scp" as a separate command). This means that for some reason bash is treating "sudo scp" as a single word instead of two.